# TypeScript struggles with type inference on tuple union

Tags: typescript, type-inference

Any pointers on why TypeScript seems to be struggling with the following type definition?

```js
type ValidationBehaviorFunction = (info: 'foo') => boolean | void

type ValidationBehavior = string | ValidationBehaviorFunction

type SimpleRule<TParameter = any> = (value: TParameter) => any

type FieldSimpleRule<TParameter = any> =
  | [ValidationBehavior, SimpleRule<TParameter>]
  | [SimpleRule<TParameter>, number]

// Parameter 'x' implicitly has an 'any' type. (7006)
const a: FieldSimpleRule<string> = [x => true, x => x]
const b: FieldSimpleRule<string> = ['', x => x]
// Parameter 'x' implicitly has an 'any' type. (7006)
const c: FieldSimpleRule<string> = [x => x, 100]
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwJYBM7CQewHYCEIAWcAblgE4BiArtgMYY5QC8UAFEtgGaYBcUA5N0z8AlMwB8UAEaZMCCHGxQAPlGKZUAKE2hIsRKnRY8hEuWZQAzsDIcA5iv3I0DE0VKZKNese27oAMpIALZg8gBKVPIAPAAqAApwZHDBEMAQZBaKIJIsrMSIVBB8CUkpaRliTJLZfuDQFEgQCChBoRFREHGJyanpmSzZuZpQjgDa8M5GOPju5AA0UG1hEJExpb0VZOIAuiPjyx3rPeX94ovYVMFSGXuaAPT3UCd9GQIAHvxQIWFItEjABAgKBESxQRQCbJffwAOjYAHYAAyIgBsIk0tBw1nBfEazVaPyOXWstmwdlyUDG7wkUBsRUW1OqUHee0x2GxUlxTRah1WnWiJPsFLG-H4DJpLIeTxeWw+X0JfwBQJBcDBEP4UNp9ThrCRqPRbOxtC5+N5a2JNiFFipEsWAEZkXsgA)

Thanks

---

**Update**

[Playground Link with more generic example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UAUBDAXFAdgVwLYCMIAnASgQD4s9CiAoUSKAIQWXwwGdgiBLTAczLxKXXgNr1w0ACqsA2jAA0VAsQC6UAD5Q5TZaL781EgMYB7TFyjAAjBlmI5ADwpQnymwAZPx85eDWAEz28i7CbsoA5JHGQA)

Comment: I think contextual type inference of union-typed callback parameters will only happen if you have a discriminated union (you don't, `SimpleRule` and `number` are not discriminants) *and* if you are not using a tuple (which I see empirically but I can't find a reason for that yet).

Comment: Removing the parameter `info` from `ValidationBehaviorFunction` resolves the inference problem btw

Comment: I see [ms/TS#43122](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43122) and [ms/TS#45522](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/45522) about inference being weird with tuples, but I don't know if the underlying cause is the same.  If I can't find anything definitive I might open a bug report (but probably not today)